# Get Latest Record of the day for a user in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get latest record of the day for a user if there is multiple entries of same user in table of the same per day.

For-example:

```
Id      UserName               CreatedOn
1       B               2018-11-20
2       A               2018-12-20
3       A               2018-11-19
4       B               2018-11-18
```

I want result For User A,B Like:

```
Id      UserName               CreatedOn
2       A               2018-12-20
1       B               2018-11-20
```

Comment: Why is ID 4 not returned? As you have no time value, what defines that a row is "more" recent, `ID` has a higher value? (Considering that the value of `ID` is getting **larger** the further back you go, that would *imply* that the lower the number the more recent.)

Comment: i am looking for User A right now

Comment: More sample data is required; your current result could be obtained from your data simply using `select * from table where username = 'A'`

Comment: can some one check my update requirement?

Comment: Your latest edit only confuses things more. You state *"How to get **Per day latest record** of user if there is multiple Users entry of same user in table per day"*. So, based on your data, every row in your sample data should be returned. They are all the "most recent" row for that day, as no user has multiple entries on the **same** day.

Comment: @Larnu , what I have understood is that, now matter the number of day, he just wants the latest record of the day/days.

Comment: @ShailendraPal . . . Your question makes no sense.  Your title suggests multiple records on the same date, but t he sample data doesn't have that.

Answer (score 4):

```
Create Table #tbl
(
Id Int,
UserName VarChar(25),
CreatedOn Date
)

Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,'B','2018-11-20'),
(2,'A','2018-12-20'),
(3,'A','2018-11-19'),
(4,'B','2018-11-18')


Select Username, Max(CreatedOn) As LastDT from #tbl
Group By UserName
```

Result:

```
Username    LastDT
A           2018-12-20
B           2018-11-20
```

UPDATE: This will work if grouping by day: Using a year selection with [DateTime]

```
Create Table #tbl
(
Id Int,
UserName VarChar(25),
CreatedOn DateTime
)

Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,'B','2018-11-20 10:45:12.000'),
(2,'A','2018-12-20 07:45:12.000'),
(3,'A','2018-11-19 09:45:12.000'),
(4,'B','2018-11-18 11:45:12.000'),
(5,'B','2018-11-20 01:50:12.000')

 Select  Username, Max(CreatedOn) As LastDT from #tbl
Where DatePart(year,CreatedOn) = '2018'
Group By UserName, DatePart(dayofyear ,CreatedOn)
Order By UserName
```

Result by day:

```
Username    LastDT
A           2018-11-19 09:45:12.000
A           2018-12-20 07:45:12.000
B           2018-11-18 11:45:12.000
B           2018-11-20 10:45:12.000
```

Comment: I believe it will give the latest record of all time, what he needs is the latest record of each day.

Comment: @affanBajwa, I updated to allow for grouping by day.  The sample data did not allow for this, so I provided a DateTime field to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just simply want the latest record per user

```
select  *
from    (
            select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by UserName order by CreatedOn desc)
            from    yourtable
        ) d
where   d.rn = 1
order by CreatedOn desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank` as in the following sql statement

```
  with t(Id, UserName, CreatedOn) as
  (
   select 1,'B',date'2018-11-20' from dual union all
   select 2,'A',date'2018-12-20' from dual union all
   select 3,'A',date'2018-11-19' from dual union all
   select 4,'B',date'2018-11-18' from dual
  )
  select Id, UserName, CreatedOn
    from
    (
    select *,
           dense_rank() over ( partition by username order by CreatedOn desc) as
           max_CreatedOn 
      from t 
    ) q
   where max_CreatedOn = 1;

Id  UserName    CreatedOn
--  --------    ----------
2   A           2018-12-20
1   B           2018-11-20
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/SKINX44567)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest record for each user, then it should work :

```
SELECT UserName, MAX(CreatedOn) FROM yourTable GROUP BY UserName
```

It will return the latest entry for each user

Output :

```
UserName       CreatedOn
    A          2018-12-20
    B          2018-11-20
```

Comment: But the OP is expecting 2 rows, not 1.

Comment: Edited after OP clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of **A** alone records means, the below query

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE UserName = 'A' ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
```

If you want particular number of **A** rows means,

```
SELECT top 2 * FROM myTable WHERE UserName = 'A' ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using WITH TIES function in sql server

```
SELECT TOP 2 WITH TIES UserName,CreatedOn  
FROM #tbl
ORDER BY ( ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC ))
```

Result

```
UserName    CreatedOn
-----------------------
  A         2018-12-20
  B         2018-11-20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query using `TOP` keyword and `inner join`

```
Create Table #temp
(
Id Int,
UserName VarChar(25),
CreatedOn Date
)

Insert Into #temp Values
(1,'B','2018-11-20'),
(2,'A','2018-12-20'),
(3,'A','2018-11-19'),
(4,'B','2018-11-18')

Select #temp.Id, #temp.UserName, #temp.CreatedOn from #temp 
inner join
(
Select Top 2 MAX(Id) as Id, UserName, CreatedOn from #temp 
group by UserName,CreatedOn ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
)a on a.Id = #temp.Id
```

The output is as shown below

```
Id  UserName    CreatedOn
-------------------------
2   A          2018-12-20
1   B          2018-11-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, you seem to want `top (1) with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by t.createdon desc;
```

If your date really has a time component, then you want to extract the date:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by convert(date, t.createdon) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data Preparation:**

```
Create Table #tbl
(
Id Int,
UserName VarChar(25),
CreatedOn Date
)

Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,'B','2018-11-20'),
(2,'A','2018-12-20'),
(3,'A','2018-11-19'),
(4,'B','2018-11-18')
```

**Solution :** Try with this simple approach :

```
    SELECT #tbl.Id, t.UserName, t.CreatedOn
    FROM   (
             SELECT Username  AS UserName, MAX(CreatedOn)     CreatedOn
             FROM   #tbl
             GROUP BY UserName
           ) t
    INNER JOIN #tbl ON  #tbl.CreatedOn = t.CreatedOn
    ORDER BY  #tbl.UserName
```

**Result:**

```
Id  UserName    CreatedOn
2     A         2018-12-20
1     B         2018-11-20
```